# Laravel Query Builder Join 3 table and count result

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I'm hanging in this, and , hope someone can bring me out this task. i have 4 table called "LOCATIONS","COUNTRIES","REGIONS"AND "DISTRICT".

LOCATIONS

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | country |
| 2 | region |
| 3 | district |
| id | name |

COUNTRIES

| id | location_id | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | India |
| 2 | 1 | Italy |
| 3 | 1 | Philippines |
| 4 | 1 | Japan |
| 5 | 1 | Taiwan |
| 6 | 1 | Canada |
| 7 | 1 | USA |
| 8 | 1 | Russia |

REGIONS

| id | location_id | country_id | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Region1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | Region3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | Region8 |

DISTRICT

| id | location_id | region_id | district |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | district 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | district 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | district 8 |

Desired Output

| COUNTRY | REGION | DISTRICT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| India | 0 | 0 |
| Italy | 2 | 0 |
| Philippines | 1 | 3 |
| Japan | 0 | 0 |
| Taiwan | 0 | 0 |
| Canada | 0 | 0 |
| USA | 0 | 0 |
| Russia | 0 | 0 |

MY QUERY is working but groupby is not working when i apply and only 2 country will appear.

```
$getcountry = LocationModel::join('location_country as country','country.location_id','locations.id')
    ->join('locations_region','locations_region.country_id','=','country.id')
    ->select([
        'locations.*',
        'country.*',
        'locations_region.*'
    ])
    ->orderBy('country.country')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: because the join will return the matching values do you want the all columns whether they are matching or not

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code: `'locations_region.*']); ->orderBy(`

Comment: @Basharmal  yes, i want to display all country. The sub region and district is a number if how many region and district for that country.

Comment: You should not be using `join` when you have proper relationships set up between your models.

Comment: how? can you give a similar or related sample/tutorial, please

Comment: i try 2 table like below, but stil not work. ```$getregion = LocationRegionModel::where('temp_status','=', 1)->select('locations_region.*')->groupBy('country_id');
                $getcountry = LocationCountyModel::joinSub($getregion,'location_country', function($join) {
                    $join->on('locations_region.location_id','=','location_country.location_id');
                })->get();```